# Can someone explain to me the Rokhsar-Kivelson Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-spin, lattice-model, topological-phase, spin-models

The following paper shows the hamiltonian of the 2D quantum dimer gas (page 2)

http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/ClaudioCastelnovo/Talks/050209_MIT.pdf

Here are some questions I have.

- Why is one term kinetic and the other potenial? Since it is all about singlet states, wouldn't they all be potential?
- What is the significance of the t and v variables?
- what are the eignenstates of said hamiltonian?

I'm also not sure how the 2d dimer gas comes as a result of the fractional quantum hall effect. Can anyone explain that to me ?

Comment: The link appears to be broken.